# Handling subpackages with same name in Python

Tags: python, import, package

I have a Python project with the following structure:

```py
my_project
|--- __init__.py
|--- client
|   |--- __init__.py
|   |--- client.py
|--- server
|   |--- __init__.py
|   |--- server.py
|   |--- models
|       |--- __init__.py
|       |--- model_1.py
|--- models
|   |--- __init__.py
|   |--- model_2.py
```

The top-level package `models` contains classes that are shared between the `server` and `client` code, while the package `models` inside the `server` package contains classes used only by the server. All the `__init__.py` files are empty.

I want to be able to import both the `models` packages into the `server` package. Importing `model_1` using `from models.model_1 import X` works well inside `server.py`.

Now, to import `model_2` from the shared `models` package in `server.py`:

1. `from ..models.model_2 import Y` returns `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
2. `import ..models.model_2` is not correct Python syntax
3. `from models.model_2 import Y` returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models.model_2'`

How can I import `models/models_2.py` from `server.py`? Ideally I'd like to avoid messing with `os.path` and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to get it to work and if anyone else is struggling with this (and I've seen that a lot of people do have problems with how Python handles subpackages and relative imports) the easiest solution was to put everything into a `my_project` package and so I could import the "higher level" `models` as `my_project.models` and the server models as `my_project.sever.models`.

Don't know if there's a more "elegant" or "Pythonic" way to do it, but this seems to work quite well without the need to change my project structure too much, install any 3rd party code to handle it or modify the path.